# MVC can't find Views after converting to ASPNET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are converting an MVC/Angular web site from ASPNET Core 2.2 to ASPNET Core 3.1. I have got the build to run with no errors or warnings, but when it starts up (in Visual Studio 2019), it looks for Home/Index, finds the controller fine, and looks for the Home/Index View, but it fails to find it even though it is there (in Views/Home/Index.cshtml), right where it's supposed to be (and right where it's been for the several months that we have been developing this site.  I have it now reduced to a test case that I can set the web project file  to netcoreapp2.2 and the site runs fine, then stop it and change the  to netcoreapp3.1, with no other changes, and it fails.  The errors are exactly what you would expect if the file were missing:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>
> /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

But the file is there!  I'm completely baffled.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show your `Startup` and the related codes/migrations?

Comment: you have to specify in startup. configureservices: services.AddControllersWithViews(); then in Configure: .app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();}); something like that, or whatever setup you need.

Comment: John, I have used the EnableEndpointRouting=false option in the services.AddMvc call.  I was trying to make the minimal changes from 2.2.  If  I hadn't done that or made the changes you suggested, I would get an InvalidOp exception, not a missing View.  But, for the record, I have also tried the changes you suggest, with the same result - the site runs, but it can't find the View, even though it's there.

Comment: itminus, I appreciate that the Startup could be relevant, but I'm forbidden by security considerations to upload code. The thing is that the startup works fine in 2.2, and doesn't work when I change the project framework to netcoreapp3.1.  If there's something specific about the startup, I may be able to answer that.

Answer (score 3):

We just had a similar issue with partials: after upgrading a web app from core 2.2 to 3.1 partial views could not be found. The solution for us was to replace this...

```
services.AddMvc();
```

... with ...

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Although I believe .AddMvc() is equivalent to .AddControllersWithViews() plus .AddRazorPages it doesn't include the runtime compilation part out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
`app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "areas",
              template: "{area=User}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });`
```

With

```
`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });`
```

*They replaced the **app.UseMvc** to **app.UseEndponts** when migrating from .Net Core 2 to .Net Core 3.*

And also if you have another Views Folder, copy the **_ViewImports.cshtml** and **_ViewStart.cshtml** from the existing Views folder to the other Views Folders.

Answer (score 0):

Check the part about routing adjustments - see [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code)

Most likely you need to change this in your `Startup` class:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

with that:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

For me it was this in project file:

```
<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
<RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>
```

I had to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`:

```
install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
```

Then add `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` after `services.AddControllersWithViews()` line in **startup.cs**:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```